# Lucene: How to give less weight to Wordnet synonyms?

Tags: lucene, wordnet

Looking at the WordnetSynonymParser class, I find no way to attach the weight of word extended (to .setBoost to synonyms to 0.2).

I would want to have 
`"word"` -> `"word synonym^0.2"`

synonym being only 20% the weight of regular word.

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to do this, since synonym parser just adding synonym tokens at the same position - take a look at the [code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.java#L205). Also **SynonymMap** is just really key-value store.